# Azure Webjobs and Servicebus Trigger - Cannot find functions after nuget package upgrade

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

I'm not sure if something has changed, but our Windows Azure webjob JobHost is no longer seeing the functions included in the Functions.cs File. We have just recently upgraded the Azure Nuget packages on this solution (not sure if that is related).

Program.cs

```
using M5Worker.Classes;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using System;
using TuesPechkin;

namespace M5Worker
{
    // To learn more about Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK, please see    http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320976
public class Program
{
    // This is needed for pechkin do not remove!
    public static readonly IConverter converter =
                               new ThreadSafeConverter(
                                   new PdfToolset(
                                       new Win64EmbeddedDeployment(
                                           new TempFolderDeployment())));

    //published with devmode false
    public static bool DevMode = false;
  // Please set the following connection strings in app.config for this WebJob to run:
    // AzureWebJobsDashboard and AzureWebJobsStorage
    public static void Main()
    {
        libUFE.clsLogging cLog = new libUFE.clsLogging("M5");
        try
        {
            cLog.LogWrite(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 0, "", "", "Information", "M5Worker has Started", 0, "");

            JobHostConfiguration jhc = new JobHostConfiguration();

            if (DevMode == false)
            {
                jhc.ServiceBusConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.strSBConnProd;
            }
            else
            {
                jhc.ServiceBusConnectionString = Properties.Settings.Default.strSBConnDev;
            }
            jhc.DashboardConnectionString = "##################";
            jhc.StorageConnectionString = "##################";
            jhc.Queues.MaxPollingInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30);
            jhc.NameResolver = new QueueNameResolver();

            JobHost jh = new JobHost(jhc);
            jh.RunAndBlock();

            cLog.LogWrite(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 0, "", "", "Information", "M5Worker has Finished", 0, "");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            cLog.LogWrite(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 0, "", "", "Error", ex.Message, 0, "");
            cLog.LogWrite(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 0, "", "", "Information", "M5Worker has Finished", 0, "");
        }
    }

    public class QueueNameResolver : INameResolver
    {
        public string Resolve(string name)
        {
            if (DevMode == true)
                return "m5queuedev";
            else
                return "m5queue";
        }
    }
```

Function.cs

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using M5Worker.DB;
using System.Threading;
using System.Data;
using M5Worker.Classes;

namespace M5Worker
{

    public class Functions
    {

        public static libUFE.clsLogging cLog = new libUFE.clsLogging("M5");

        // This function will get triggered/executed when a new message is written 
        // on an Azure Queue called queue.
        public static void M5Worker([ServiceBusTrigger("%queuename%")] BrokeredMessage message)
        {
            if (message != null)
            {
                try
                {

                    if (message.Properties.Count > 0 && message.Properties.ContainsKey("Function"))
                    {
                        //message.Complete();
                        switch (message.Properties["Function"].ToString().ToUpper())
                        {
                            case "CREATEELECTRONICFORECLOSURE":
                                FunctionHandler.ProcessMessage(message, clsElectronicForeclosure.processItem, true);
                                break;

                            case "PROCESSCUSTOMER":
                                FunctionHandler.ProcessMessage(message, clsProcessCustomer.ProcessCustomerObject, true);
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Message does not contain function");
                    }
                }
                catch (System.Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                    cLog.LogWrite(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name, 0, "", "", "Error", ex.Message, 0, "");
                    // Indicate a problem, unlock message in queue
                    message.DeadLetter();
                }


                message.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }


}
```

Results in 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ocZ5.jpg

I've been searching around and found answers related to making sure the functions classes are public static, but not much more.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are the old and new package versions at play? Can you try going back to your earlier commit to isolate whether it's indeed related to the package upgrade, or something else unrelated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You now have to add an additional line in your startup code "config.UseServiceBus()" to register ServiceBus support. See example here: http://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/ServiceBus/Program.cs#L26

We did this to decouple ServiceBus from the core WebHobs SDK libraries, and we also moved it onto the new extensibility model.

Please add that line to your startup code and you should be good.